# Jquery переменная в качестве параметра функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function slider(slid, slider, conteinerSlider){
  let widthSlid = $('.slid').outerWidth(true),
      widthSlider = $('.slider').outerWidth(),
      widthConteinerSlider = $('.conteinerSlider').outerWidth();
};
```

Помогите товарищи, только начал осваивать jquery и не могу разобраться как передать переменную типа $('.переменная') в параметрах функции

Comment: А как вы пробуете? Передаётся как и все остальные переменные

Comment: `let widthSlid = $('.'+slid').outerWidth(true),`